# Table model cannot converted to String

Tags: java, double, tablemodel

```
private void createNewMemberCheckInRecord(){
         int row = bookingTable.getSelectedRow();
         if(row<0){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a booking","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
         else{
            final String roomType = ((BookingTableModel)bookingTable.getModel()).getValueAt(row,3).toString();
            =============================================================
            final double totalPrice = (Double.parseDouble((BookingTableModel)bookingTable.getModel()).getValueAt(row,9).toString());
             =============================================================
            final String memberName = ((BookingTableModel)bookingTable.getModel()).getValueAt(row,7).toString();
            final String receptionistName = ((BookingTableModel)bookingTable.getModel()).getValueAt(row,8).toString();
            final String appStatus = ((BookingTableModel)bookingTable.getModel()).getValueAt(row,5).toString();
            final String appID = ((BookingTableModel)bookingTable.getModel()).getValueAt(row,0).toString();
            if(appStatus.equals("CheckOut") || appStatus.equals("Cancel")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The booking either CheckOut or canceled","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
               SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       CheckInRecordServiceJFrame checkInRecordServiceJFrame = new CheckInRecordServiceJFrame(getPanel(),roomType,memberName,receptionistName,totalPrice,appID);
                   }
               });
            }
         }
}
```

I have a problem is i can't convert table model to String .In the code above i want convert double to string,but it got errors.Please help me this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(bookingTable.getModel().getValueAt(row,9).toString());
```